# NFS Mounts on High Sierra (and autofsd mounts)

Tags: mount, nfs, macos-highsierra

NFS Mounts stopped working after upgrade to High Sierra. This is specific to a QNap NAS as our Synology NAS is still mounting as expected. Mounts are exported NFS 3.

```
mount -v -o rsize=32768,wsize=32768,intr,noatime -t nfs sw1:/Company/jobs /companyjobs
mount_nfs: warning: option "nfssvers" not known
mount_nfs: can't mount /Company/jobs from sw1 onto /companyjobs: RPC prog. not avail
```

Is NFS 3 and earlier support no longer available?

Comment: the mount does mount via finder `cmd-k` with url `nfs://sw1/Company/jobs`

Answer (score 0):

I enabled NFS V4 as well as V2,3 on the QNAP NAS and the mounts seem to work now.